# GCP - AppEngine

Tags: typescript, gcloud

Trying to deploy a service, this is the entry point to my service:

```js
import { createServer } from '@marblejs/core';
import { IO } from 'fp-ts/lib/IO';
import { listener } from './api/http.listener';
import { GLOBAL } from './environment/environment';

const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || GLOBAL().environment.port;

const server = createServer({
    port: PORT,
    hostname: GLOBAL().environment.host,
    listener,
});

const main: IO<void> = async () => await (await server)();

main();
```

My gcloud file looks like this:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16
entrypoint: npm run prod
service: ext-mapbox
```

I also setup a config file in my environment:

```json
{
  "host": "https://ext-mapbox-dot-log430-g01-e01.nn.r.appspot.com",
  "port": 4005,
  "mapboxApi": {
    "baseUrl": "https://api.mapbox.com/",
    "directionApiEndpoint": "directions/v5/mapbox/driving-traffic",
    "key": "pk.<...>"
  }
}
```

When I am deploying with the `gcloud app deploy` command everything works fine but the enpoint doesn't seem to be working when doing a GET command on the intended enpoint.

Comment: Please share any error messages you are getting.

Comment: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
 [start] 2021/10/06 20:10:02.014897 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/invalid"